# How to do Ajax call load content in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying load  content via Ajax in a Wordpress theme.

It works on a simple HTML template site but not in WordPress theme. Do I need to add a function in my function.php?

Here is the simple HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
            // don't cache ajax or content won't be fresh
            $.ajaxSetup ({
                cache: false
            });   var ajax_load = "<img src='small-loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

        // load() functions
            var loadUrl = "//localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/searchform.php";
            $("#loadbasic").click(function(){
                $("#panel-result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);});});
      </script>
<div class="excontainer">

  <div id="loadbasic">basic load</div>
    <div id="panel-result"></div>

</div>
```

How would this be implemented into a Wordpress theme? Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Use a noConflict wrapper: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: [I wrote a thorough walk through on how to get AJAX working in Wordpress here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26950030/1922144)