# Wordpress - How to use jquery .load with WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'd like to use the jQuery function .load in Wordpress but can't get it to work.

My goal is to remove some tags if a user is not logged in.
The PHP file replies 0 if the user is NOT logged in and 1 if the user IS logged in.

The ajax section of my script works fine when run alone but it executes on all pages which I would like to avoid (Just like the INIT hook).

The .load part should filter this and only execute when a tag id is (#hfwp_Calc_Weight) present on the page.

Just for info: I'v already used Enqueue & Add action so it is done the WP way.

```
(function($) {

   $(document).ready(function() {


$( "#hfwp_Calc_Weight" ).load(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {action: 'hfwpUserLoggedIn'},
      success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         if ( response > 0 ) {
            $( "#hfwp_gender_label" ).remove();
            $( "#hfwp_gender" ).remove();
         }else {
            $("#feedback").text("Not Logged in");
         }
      }
   });
});


}); //End Document.Ready

})(jQuery); //End Wordpress jQuery Wrapper
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941256/jquery-load-wordpress-pages-via-ajax

Comment: It seems a bit backward to me, why not check if the user is logged in when the page is being rendered and not output the tags?

Comment: Possible your right.
The examples I've seen so far are based in the Init hook which runs on every page.

I wanted to avoid the overhead this this creates since the tag is only placed on a few pages.