# Wordpress: Return page's HTML from post id (ajax)

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I followed the instructions from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26950030/9200273

I'm able to return data from the Ajax template based on the post id that is passed into it.

This is what the template looks like (basically the same as the answer I posted):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ajax
*/

$post = get_post($_POST['id']);

if ($post) {
    setup_postdata($post); ?> 

    <div><?php the_title();?></div>

<?php }
```

So when I click a link, my ajax logic will replace contents in a div with what is returned. in this case just the title of the post/page.

How can I return what the page content would have been if I wasn't using ajax? Like my **custom page templates** and their content.

My JS:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.nav-header a', function( e ) {
 e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

    if( pageurl != window.location ) {
        window.history.pushState( {path: pageurl}, '', pageurl);
    }

    if ( $(this).parent().attr('class') != "logo" ) {
        var postID = $(this).parent().attr("class").split('page-item-').pop().split(' ')[0];
    } else {
        var postID = $(this).attr("class").split('page-item-').pop().split(' ')[0];
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: wp_vars.httpHost,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: postID
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("main.main-wrap").children().remove();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("main.main-wrap").append($(data));
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the post content when you have your post class saved into a $post variable use this.

```
<?php echo $post->post_content; ?>
```

Comment: not what i'm looking for sorry. I'm trying to load entire pages via ajax. maybe i can't do it the way I structured everything. the SO answer i followed said you could.